# Changed name of user, but File Manager always open to home dir of old username

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, kde, users, kubuntu

Ubuntu KDE 22.04.1 (Kubuntu)

I changed a user's name from john to dave. I did so using

```
sudo usermod -l dave -m -d /home/dave john
```

After making the change, I restarted the machine. At first glance, there were no issues.

However, when I opened the File Manager (Dolphin) application, each directory shown (i.e. downloads, documents, pictures) tried opening to /home/john.

As a result, each time I clicked on Downloads, for example, I received an error message saying "The file or folder /home/john/Downloads does not exist."

How do I get the File Manager to look in /home/dave by default?

Please note that this issue occurs when I'm logged in as dave

Answer (score 1):

Dolphin maintains a cache of known places `~/.local/share/apps/kfileplaces/bookmarks.xml` . You may try to delete it and log-off, and log-in again. Or delete the entire folder if needed. Please remember to backup files first, you may need to rollback changes.

Answer (score 0):

It might take some time to reflect the changes everywhere. After clearing cache, try renaming the user from GUI. Also, download all the files from GUI until the command line works!